# Permission denied for lock.db and trace.db file

Tags: docker, openshift, h2

The lock.db and trace.db files are getting created in root and the docker container is not able to start due to that.

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/batch-db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
    username: batch-db
    password:
    hikari:
        auto-commit: false
h2:
    console:
        enabled: false
```

Container Error:

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/batch-db.trace.db", cause: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /batch-db.trace.db (Permission denied)" [90034-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.logWritingError(TraceSystem.java:289)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:310)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.writeFile(TraceSystem.java:258)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.write(TraceSystem.java:242)
    at org.h2.message.Trace.error(Trace.java:196)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:314)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:280)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:66)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:179)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:157)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:140)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:351)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Log file error: "/batch-db.trace.db", cause: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /batch-db.trace.db (Permission denied)" [90034-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /batch-db.trace.db (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newOutputStream(FilePathDisk.java:287)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newOutputStream(FileUtils.java:236)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:306)
    ... 23 more
2020-08-19 18:15:19.559 DEBUG 1 --- [HelperThread-#0] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error opening database: "Could not save properties /batch-db.lock.db" [8000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.getExceptionFatal(FileLock.java:428)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.save(FileLock.java:196)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:322)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:108)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:674)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:286)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:280)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:66)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:179)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:157)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:140)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:351)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /batch-db.lock.db (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newOutputStream(FilePathDisk.java:287)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newOutputStream(FileUtils.java:236)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.save(FileLock.java:187)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I can't run the container as root and need to specify the path where the lock.db and trace.db should be created.

I read through the documentation and couldn't figure out the way to specify those.

Comment: H2 creates them in the same directory where your database is located and there are no related settings. It looks like some environment problem, maybe `/tmp` in the container is a symlink to `/`?

Comment: I checked and there is no symbolic links which are making /tmp linked to /